# Что если обратиться к обычной функции в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

У меня есть бот на aiogram и нужно обратиться к обычной функции, смогу ли я это сделать?

```
def stop_for_5_sec():
    time.sleep(5)
    return

@do.message_handler():
async def hello(msg):
    stop_for_5_sec()
    await msg.answer(“Hi”)
```

Правильно ли это или нужно добавить “async” к обычной функции?

Comment: Конечно, вам ничего не мешает это сделать, но весь ваш код должен быть приведен к асинхронности (: в том числе и ваши функции.

Comment: Можете подсказать, в итоге к функции stop_for_5sec нужно приписывать async?